# Account/Client On-boarding process

Tags: community, workflow, account, process-builder, validation-rule

Very basic question here: saw someone's SF the other day where, while using completely native SF functionality (no Apex/Visualforce) the user was able to create a client/account on-boarding process that moved down (what appeared to be) a single new record page, over the course of the whole process where the page started mostly grayed out, with only a few prospect-oriented fields editable.  As certain fields were filled out and criteria met, the next portion of the page would become editable.

I have been looking at Workflow Rules, Process Builder, and Field Validation Rules trying to replicate but as yet have been unable to do so.

I'm sure the answer is quite basic and I'm just unaware. Any pointers would be fantastic. Much appreciated.

Comment: I believe there had to be some sort of vf, hack, managed package, or code that was doing this and you just did not see it. The Native UI does not do this

Answer (score 0):

If all of the fields are picklists (or checkbox for a controlling field), you could set up dependencies so that certain picklist fields are greyed-out until the controlling picklist has a value set.

If you haven't worked with dependent picklists yet, the numbered steps in this guide are a good quickstart into creating field dependencies: [Create a Dependent Picklist](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.salesforce1api.meta/salesforce1api/pages_quick_start_dependent_picklists.htm)

Comment: Thanks Martin, 

It wasn't just the fields that were grayed out though, it was the entire portion of the page.  It's almost as if the next "step" in the process became unlocked when certain criteria were met.

Comment: I don't think that exists yet for standard page layouts, but it sounds like a good [idea](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000BroxAAC).

Comment: Okay!! Thanks for your help. Maybe the dependent pick list idea will work for our purposes.